# Backslash character in string causes string to evaluate as "nothing" in WCF

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have a WCF application, written in VB.NET that takes a generic `Dictionary(Of String, String)` as one of the parameters.
When I pass in a Key/Value pair that has a backslash `\` as one of the characters in the value, the client automatically changes the entire value to `Nothing` or in the XML it shows this:

```
<Value i:nil="true />
```

Is there some special way to escape backslashes when passing them in a string to a WCF service? As far as I know the backslash isn't a reserved character in XML.

Comment: Code blocks need a blank line before them to show up. By the way, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you calling your service? I've just tried this scenario (see code below), and the server prints the values correctly.

```
Public Class StackOverflow_6116861_751090
    <ServiceContract()> _
    Public Interface ITest
        <OperationContract()> Sub Process(ByVal dict As Dictionary(Of String, String))
    End Interface

    Public Class Service
        Implements ITest

        Public Sub Process(ByVal dict As System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)) Implements ITest.Process
            For Each key In dict.Keys
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, dict(key))
            Next
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Shared Sub Test()
        Dim baseAddress As String = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service"
        Dim host As ServiceHost = New ServiceHost(GetType(Service), New Uri(baseAddress))
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(ITest), New BasicHttpBinding(), "")
        host.Open()
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened")

        Dim factory As ChannelFactory(Of ITest) = New ChannelFactory(Of ITest)(New BasicHttpBinding(), New EndpointAddress(baseAddress))
        Dim proxy As ITest = factory.CreateChannel()

        Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        dict.Add("o\ne", "uno")
        dict.Add("two", "do\s")
        dict.Add("th\ree", "tr\es")
        proxy.Process(dict)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I found the source of the problem. I was calling the service from the WCF test client, which did not automatically escape the backslash character like VB would do if it was calling the service. It works fine from within a program.